# Swipe gesture without messing the navigation bar?

Tags: xcode, view, tableview

This is hard to explain but i'll try my best. I have a Table View controller that leads to 10 View controller. All the View controllers have a navigation bar title (The titles are the 10 objects from the Table view controller). Now i want to add the Swipe Gesture for a easier navigation between the 10 table view items (Instead of going back to the Table view manually i want the user to be able to swipe to change from a view controller to another). HERE'S THE PROBLEM: When i add the Swipe Gesture and i connect it from one view to another, it asks if i want the action to be either: Push, Modal or custom. Now, if i choose one of them, it makes the navigation bar title disappear. I want to keep the title without messing up the connection from the table view to the views controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want a pageviewcontroller. Set up the pages to be your different view controllers

A pageviewcontroller essentially allows you to do exactly what you want to do without having to setup a new segue every single time. That way it can all happen under one navigation bar. If you've seen the twitter app, you know how you can scroll through your feeds? Same thing.

There are tons of tutorials on the web, but pageviewcontroller a can be a tiny bit tricky because they require some logic

Here's a slightly more advanced thing that might be useful to you:

https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers